# Python Check For Duplicate Values In A Object Array

Tags: python

I have a array which stores a object. I am trying to see if there are duplicate values in this object array, but only on one of the objects parameters (hexdigest).

How can I check for duplicates and record the entire object of duplicates I find?

```
# class to store hashes
class customclass: 
    def __init__(self, value, hexdigest): 
        self.value = value 
        self.hexdigest = hexdigest

# array to store class data
hash_array = []
hash_array.append(customclass(value=299, hexdigest='927'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=207, hexdigest='92b'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=113, hexdigest='951'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=187, hexdigest='951'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=205, hexdigest='998'))

# sort array
sorted_array = sorted(hash_array, key=attrgetter('hexdigest'))

# check for duplicate hexdigest's
newlist = []
duplist = []
for obj in sorted_array:
    for jbo in newlist:
        if obj.hexdigest not in jbo:
            newlist.append(obj)
        else:
            duplist.append(obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hex_list = []
duplist = []
for obj in sorted_array:
    if(obj.hexdigest in hex_list):
        duplist.append(obj)
    else:
        hex_list.append(obj.hexdigest)
```

use this above block of code instead of the below one which you have implemented to find the list of duplicate object

```
newlist = []
duplist = []
for obj in sorted_array:
    for jbo in newlist:
        if obj.hexdigest not in jbo:
            newlist.append(obj)
        else:
            duplist.append(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `newlist` is empty, so the inner for loop never runs, so nothing gets appended to `newlist` or `duplist`.

You may wish to *group* by the `hexdigest` attribute using `itertools.groupby` and a dictionary comprehension.

```
from operator import attrgetter
from itertools import groupby

class customclass: 
    def __init__(self, value, hexdigest): 
        self.value = value 
        self.hexdigest = hexdigest

hash_array = []
hash_array.append(customclass(value=299, hexdigest='927'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=207, hexdigest='92b'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=113, hexdigest='951'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=187, hexdigest='951'))
hash_array.append(customclass(value=205, hexdigest='998'))

sorted_array = sorted(hash_array, key=attrgetter('hexdigest'))
# [<__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2a20>, 
#  <__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a29b0>, 
#  <__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2b00>, 
#  <__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2b70>, 
#  <__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2c18>]

groups = groupby(sorted_array, key=attrgetter('hexdigest'))

{k: list(v) for k, v in groups}
# {'927': [<__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2a20>], 
#  '92b': [<__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a29b0>], 
#  '951': [<__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2b00>,  
#          <__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2b70>], 
#  '998': [<__main__.customclass object at 0x7f488d1a2c18>]}
```

From there it's relatively easy to retrieve the unique and duplicate values.

It may be easier to visualize what's going on if you provide a more useful definition for `__repr__`.

```
class customclass: 
    def __init__(self, value, hexdigest): 
        self.value = value 
        self.hexdigest = hexdigest
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<customclass value: {self.value}, hexdigest: {self.hexdigest}>"
```

Doing so, `hash_array` prints in the interactive interpreter as follows, with the exception of he newlines I added for sanity's sake.

```
[<customclass value: 299, hexdigest: 927>, 
 <customclass value: 207, hexdigest: 92b>, 
 <customclass value: 113, hexdigest: 951>, 
 <customclass value: 187, hexdigest: 951>, 
 <customclass value: 205, hexdigest: 998>]
```